# implement external feedback form in magento

Tags: php, magento, user-feedback

I have to implement some feedback customer code for getting enroled in their store database.
the code is :

```
try {
$Client = new TrustedShop('key'); 
$Client->SetEmail();
$Client->AddProduct('Name of first purchased product');
$Client->AddProduct('Name of second purchased product');
$Client->Send();
```

Nice and simple.

The logic is that after some days, they will send my customer a feedback for asking about their shopping experience on the store.

I have currently embeded it into `/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

with the `$Client->SetEmail($this->getAddress()->getEmail());`

No problems here, but (and a big but :) ) how can i retrive the customer's ordered sku in billing phtml?
And if the ordered contains 2 or 10 skus how can i send them to my partner ?

Is this the corect path to implement the code, or there is a better location in magento where i can retrive both the customer email and the ordered skus ?

P.S. Sorry if this is a stupidly simplistic question, newbie on the throttle here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

the "dirty hack" solution:

At the `billing.phtml` the order is not yet placed, the customer can step back and quit shopping. It is not the good point to insert the logic.
Instead, use the `checkout/success.phtml` template for the hack. You can do the following there:

```
<?php 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
Mage::log($order->getCustomerEmail());
Mage::log($order->getCustomerFirstname());
Mage::log($order->getCustomerLastname());
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
Mage::log($item->getSku());
};
?>
```

And that's it, you have all the data to implement the custom logic.

The RECOMMENDED solution starts here:

As i understand, you will have to send the name or SKU of ordered products an the customer's email to an external client. 
Magento has an event-driven architecture, so in issues like this it is much better to create an Observer to catch an event. [(link to "how to create Observer")](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) The event in your case is "sales_order_place_after". For this you need in your module's config eg. app/code/local/YOUR/MODULE/etc/config.xml:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <any_unique_name_of_your_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>yourclass/observer</class>
                <method>sendOrderInfo</method>
            </any_unique_name_of_your_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

And in you Observer, which is app/code/local/YOUR/MODULE/Model/Observer.php:

```
class YOUR_MODULE_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
public function sendOrderInfo($observer)
{
#get the order
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

Mage::log($order->getBillingAddress());
Mage::log($order->getShippingAddress())
Mage::log($order->getCustomerEmail());
Mage::log($order->getCustomerFirstname());
Mage::log($order->getCustomerLastname());
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $sku = $item->getSku();
...
```

This is an example how you can retrieve the data you need, and then you can implement your custom logic inside the method of the Observer.

EDIT: a more detailed example to get the `sku` of ordered items

Comment: Damn, like i said i'm a newbie ... and from your answer i understand that i have a long way before understanding magento. From what i understand this is the corect way to modify magento's functionality, but isen't there a dirty hack possible for this? i have to send the email AND the sku, or the email AND the name of the orderd product

Comment: yahoo ... 10x so muck it works like a charm, and because this situation need's a quick solution i am going to implement the "dirty hack", but because of my guilty conscience i am learning to do this the right way by creating a custom module. Thank you so much for you answer and for learning me a thing or two about magento!